# Using commons-lang NameValuePair in android

Tags: java, android, apache, import, apache-commons

I would like to use `NameValuePair` that is part of Apache commons-lang ([link](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/)). The problem is I am getting an error when trying to initialize `NameValuePair` object, like this:

`NameValuePair pair = new NameValuePair()`

or like this:

`NameValuePair pair = new NameValuePair("name", "value")`.

Currently the only import that suggested for `NameValuePair` is `org.apache.http.NameValuePair`. So I downloaded commons-lang jar from the above link and added it to the libs folder in my project.

Still the only import option that is available is the one mentioned above.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you added the jar file to project as a library in your IDE?

Comment: yes I did, I have added a built path to he jar, source and javadoc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NameValuePair is a public interface, an abstract class. 
You should use [BasicNameValuePair](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/message/BasicNameValuePair.html) to initialize a name value pair.

for example,

```
List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("timestamp", timestamp));
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key", value));
```

Answer (score 1):

NameValuePair does not have the constructor. And this class is not included in Apache-commons jar.

Try to use [BasicNameValuePair](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/message/BasicNameValuePair.html) instead.

```
BasicNameValuePair pair = new BasicNameValuePair("name", "value");
```